# bootstrap.sh: Karpenter with custom lanuch templates

Tags: terraform, gpu, amazon-eks, karpenter

The Karpenter default OS, Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), accepts shell scripts (bash commands).

Karpenter supports using custom launch templates

In the default configuration, Karpenter uses an EKS optimized version of AL2 (Amazon Linux 2)  (https://karpenter.sh/v0.13.2/aws/launch-templates/) and passes the hostname of the Kubernetes API server, and a certificate. The EKS Optimized AMI includes a bootstrap.sh (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/bootstrap.sh) script which connects the instance to the cluster, based on the passed data.

I need to use Ubuntu 20.04 with Cuda 11.6 instead of AL2. Is there any bootstrap for Ubuntu AMI? Or any related docs I may read to write the bootstrap.sh for Ubuntu 20.04 with Cuda 11.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...need to use Ubuntu 20.04 with Cuda 11.6

Official document is [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/docs/aws/eks/), image information is [here](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/docs/aws/eks/). Deploy the GPU driver [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

> Canonical and Amazon work together to make Ubuntu worker nodes available for Amazon’s Elastic Kubernetes Services (EKS). This fully-managed service makes it easy to use Kubernetes on AWS, without being an expert in managing Kubernetes clusters.

In the link below they provide each image with the corresponding region:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/aws-eks/

These images are supposed to include the corresponding `bootsrap.sh` script.

Find more details in this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/optimized-support-amazon-eks-ubuntu-1804/).